# Retrieve lost iPhoto after replaced hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, photos.app

I replaced the hard drive on my MacBook Pro through Apple. I backed up files on my computer but not my Applications.

Is my iPhoto lost forever? I have thousands of pictures on there! I've signed in to iCloud and the iPhoto icon is not ticked. Is everything lost? Can I call Apple and retrieve my old hard drive somehow?

Comment: what happened to the original drive ? where did you back up to?

Comment: did you look in here ~/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary/Masters/  (copy paste in Finder go to

Comment: Yes there is nothing under pictures apart from the photo's I saved into that Desktop folder. When I search Finder there is no iphoto library.  When I backed up everything I specifically chose only folders on the desktop - I had completely forgotten about iPhoto as I hardly ever look at it.  But there are really important pictures on there! The original drive the Apple store never gave back to me, but I will call them now.

Comment: good luck, hope they did not toss it in the garbage. did they do the back up ?

Answer (score 1):

If you backed up all your files, then your library has been backed up and all you are missing is the iPhoto app. The iPhoto app has been replaced by Photos.app in Yosemite, so you can re-download iPhoto or Photos from the Mac App Store and your library will be automatically detected.

If you didn't back up all your files, then you need to rely on the last one thousand photos accessible in Photo Stream or Shared Photo Streams.

Comment: Thanks I'm updating to Yosemite from Mavericks now - I'm really worried though as in iCloud iPhoto icon was unticked :(

Comment: Where would I find the photo stream on my Mac, through iCloud only?

Comment: @Lilly It'll appear as part of your library once you sign in to Photo Stream in iPhoto or Photos on your Mac.

Answer (score -1):

Lilly, go to Apps purchases and if you purchase iPhoto in the past then you can download it again.